# How do I run a specific feature file using cucumber and cypress 9.7.0

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, feature-file

I have multiple feature files, I need to run a single feature file using cli. I don't want to use tags to control the file that I want to run. I want a command using that I should be able to run a specific feature. I am using cucumber preprocessor with cypress